# how to calculate the number of times a cell doesn't change in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

With the following data:

```
A
false
false
false
false
true
false
false
true
true
true
```

I would like to generate the following output:

```
A        B
false    1
false    2
false    3
false    4
true     1
false    1
false    2
true     1
true     2
true     3
```

so, at each change, I restart the counter and then increment as long as the content doesn't change.

I can do it with a loop (pseudocode):

```
count = 0
current = df['A'][0]
for i in df['A'].index:
    if df['A'][i] != current:
        current = df['A'][i]
        count = 0
    df['B'][i] = ++count
```

but is there a Panda-ish way to achieve this since the loop will be very slow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df['B'] = df.groupby(df.A.ne(df.A.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount()+1                                                                                                                 


       A      B
0  False      1
1  False      2
2  False      3
3  False      4
4   True      1
5  False      1
6  False      2
7   True      1
8   True      2
9   True      3
```